Plotly geo mapbox - toggle points based on row value
I've got a plotly mapbox setup like this
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    data,
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    zoom=4,
    height=0,
    color="Engagement",
    mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter",
    hover_data={
        "Latitude": False,
        "Longitude": False,
        "Engagement": False,
        "1st study": True,
    },
)

fig.update_layout(
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
    hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor="black", font_size=16, font_family="Lato"),
)

colour_map = {1: "#ff0000", 2: "#2a00ff", 3: "#1be43c"}

colours = [colour_map[val] for val in data["Engagement"]]

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=6, color=colours))
fig.show()

Is there a way of adding e.g. a checkbox to the map to make the points toggleable based on the Engagement value?

You can use Checklist():
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
 
 
data = {
    "Latitude": [40.7128, 34.0522, 37.7749],
    "Longitude": [-74.0060, -118.2437, -122.4194],
    "Engagement": [1, 2, 3],
    "1st study": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
 
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    data,
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    zoom=4,
    height=0,
    color="Engagement",
    mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter",
    hover_data={
        "Latitude": False,
        "Longitude": False,
        "Engagement": False,
        "1st study": True,
    },
)
 
fig.update_layout(
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
    hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor="black", font_size=16, font_family="Lato"),
)
 
colour_map = {1: "#ff0000", 2: "#2a00ff", 3: "#1be43c"}
colours = [colour_map[val] for val in data["Engagement"]]
 
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=6, color=colours))
 
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
 
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="map", figure=fig),
    html.Label("Toggle points based on Engagement value:"),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id="toggle-engagement",
        options=[
            {"label": "Engagement 1", "value": 1},
            {"label": "Engagement 2", "value": 2},
            {"label": "Engagement 3", "value": 3}
        ],
        value=[1, 2, 3],
        inline=True
    )
])
 
 
@app.callback(
    Output("map", "figure"),
    [Input("toggle-engagement", "value")]
)
 
def update_map(vals):
    opacs = [1 if val in vals else 0 for val in data["Engagement"]]
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=6, opacity=opacs))
    return fig
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)


This almost works, but the points are drawn in pure white when they're toggled "off", since the default is white. Is there a way to make them go away altogether?

@Vessel How about this?

Works perfectly, thanks!
